# KOTLIN: My data do not gets from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from my firebase realtime database.
In my database there is a table whose name is "groups" and it has 3 values "datetime", "title", "username".
I want to get title value and add my list.
Normally in static version, I have a list which includes GroupModelRetrieve types and lists the titles in listview
Now I cant see the titles in listview It is empty
I am new in mobile programming. So, I appreaciate that if you help me.

Here is my code

```
  val list: ArrayList<GroupModelRetrieve> = arrayListOf()

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        databaseReference = database?.getReference("groups")!!.child("title")
        val postListener = object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Fail to get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val data = snapshot.getValue()
                val item = GroupModelRetrieve(data.toString())
                list.add(item)
            }
        }

            databaseReference!!.addValueEventListener(postListener)


        val adapter = GroupsAdapter(requireActivity(), list)
        v.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list_view_groups).adapter = adapter
```

Also I am adding my model

```
public class GroupModelRetrieve(Title: String) {

    val title:String
    
    init {
        title = Title
    }
}
```

If you want, I can add more codes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What error are you getting? or what problem are you having?

Comment: @FelipeCruzV10 thanks for your comment. I couldnt see titles. I editedmy post

Comment: I think your problem might be with the implementation of the adapter. Where's the adapter code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to notify the list with the new changes, as by default Firebase works asynchronously to the main thread, so setting the adapter to the list will get called before any Firebase response.

```
val adapter = GroupsAdapter(requireActivity(), list)
val listView = v.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list_view_groups) // << Set listView in a variable 
listView.adapter = adapter

val list: ArrayList<GroupModelRetrieve> = arrayListOf()

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    databaseReference = database?.getReference("groups")!!.child("title")
    val postListener = object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Fail to get data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val data = snapshot.getValue()
            val item = GroupModelRetrieve(data.toString())
            list.add(item)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // <<<<<<< Here is the change
        }
    }

   databaseReference!!.addValueEventListener(postListener)
```

Also I suggest using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead of `addValueEventListener()` in case you need the list only once without the need to real-time updates

Comment: This is not working. notifyDataSetChanged method gives an error "Unresolved reference: notifyDataSetChanged"

Comment: @CerenKeklik you're right this should be called on the adapter, I fixed it now

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. In this style just one title showed. I couldnt see all titles. How can I do that

Comment: @CerenKeklik Can you debug and see if whether `onDataChange` method gets called more than one time